# How to update deprecated NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver code?

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am using the `SKCache` library to cache data in my app and I have two warnings that say that `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` related code is deprecated and should be updated. I gave it my best attempt, but I wanted to check here to get the correct answer as this is an important function of my app and I do not want to mess it up.

```
private func save(object: SKObject) throws {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
      let cacheDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let fileDirectory = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("spacekit")

      var fileDir = fileDirectory.absoluteString
      let range = fileDir.startIndex..<fileDir.index(fileDir.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
      fileDir.removeSubrange(range)

      try createFolderIfNeeded(atPath: fileDir, absolutePath: fileDirectory)

      let fileFormatedName = object.key.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) ?? object.key

      let convertedFileName = convertToBase64(withString: fileFormatedName).suffix(45).map({ String($0) }).joined()

      let fileName = fileDirectory.appendingPathComponent(convertedFileName)

      if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileName.absoluteString) || object.isUpdated {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)

        try? data.write(to: fileName)
      }
    } catch {
      throw Operations.saveFail
    }
  }
```

Specifically on this line:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
```

I was able to come up with this amended version, but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

Lastly,

```
private func load() throws {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
      let cacheDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let fileDirectory = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("spacekit")

      var fileDir = fileDirectory.absoluteString
      let range = fileDir.startIndex..<fileDir.index(fileDir.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
      fileDir.removeSubrange(range)

      try createFolderIfNeeded(atPath: fileDir, absolutePath: fileDirectory)

      let paths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: fileDir)

      for path in paths {
        if let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: fileDir + path) as? SKObject {
          if !object.isExpired {
            add(object: object)
          } else {
            try? fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileDir + path)
          }
        }
      }
    } catch {
      throw Operations.loadFail
    }
  }
```

Specifically on this line:

```
if let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: fileDir + path) as? SKObject {
```

I wasn't able to figure anything out on my own related to this as the new method does not seem to have a parameter for a file directory. I appreciate the help in advance.

**Updated:**

```
private func load() throws {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
      let cacheDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let fileDirectory = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("spacekit")

      var fileDir = fileDirectory.absoluteString
      let range = fileDir.startIndex..<fileDir.index(fileDir.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
      fileDir.removeSubrange(range)

      try createFolderIfNeeded(atPath: fileDir, absolutePath: fileDirectory)

      let paths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: fileDir)

      for path in paths {
        let objData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileDir + path))
        if let object = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [SKObject.self], from: objData) as? SKObject {
          if !object.isExpired {
            add(object: object)
          } else {
            try? fileManager.removeItem(atPath: fileDir + path)
          }
        }
      }
    } catch {
      throw Operations.loadFail
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you strip the first 7 characters of the URL string?`absoluteString` is the wrong API for file system paths. Use `path` or still better use the URL related API of FileManager.

Comment: @vadian I actually hadn't noticed that until you just pointed it out. As I mentioned in my post, this isn't my library or code.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first function, you've updated it correctly.
As for the second one,

[func unarchivedObject(ofClasses classes: [AnyClass], from data: Data) throws -> Any?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2963379-unarchivedobject) now requires `Data` param. 
And you have a path to the file where that `Data` is stored.

So you can update the code like this:

```
let objData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileDir + path))
if let object = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [MyClass.self], from: objData) {
    // check if object.isExpired, etc
}
```

---

I'd like to notice that if it's a legacy code and you have to support it, you could add some kind of unit test for this archiving/unarchiving, make it work, and then quickly update the deprecated code while being sure that the test works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question with the corrected code, however it crashes.

Comment: what’s the crash message?